# htmlHelper vs partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, html-helper

I can't decide whether I should use a htmlHelper or a partial view for solving my problem.

I would like to reuse the following code:

```
<div style="width: 500px; float: left;">
  <div class="box effect2">
    <span><a href="@Url.Action("someMethod", "somController")">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~someurl)" /></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The href and the image source would be parameters.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use partial view when you have lots of markup. Html helpers should be used to generate only small portions of HTML. In this particular case you are really on the limit and both approaches would be fine. Use the one you prefer for this particular example. I'd probably go with a custom HTML helper here as this seems quite a common widget that could be reused across various applications if you incorporate it into an assembly.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information. I've created a html helpers as per your recommendation.

Comment: Whether or not your code will be called via AJAX might be a criteria too.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think performance aspect should also be considered here. When using partial views, ControllerFactory will create the controller of partial view(if partial view has any) and it costs time. ControllerFactory will first get the partial view's location (it caches the locations of partial views but still..) and create a Controller instance which is not a small object and consumes some memory. Event if partial view doesnt have any controllers(e.g.RenderPartial), it still has to search for the Partial View. Therefore, I think that using HtmlHelpers would be better. What do you think?

Comment: @sotn, searching for the partial view costs virtually nothing because it gets cached.